# Insert Sqlite string with brackets / special characters

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

for a quiz android app I made a sqlite database with categories names. When I run a select query like this :

```
select * from QuestionBank where category = 'Adjektiv - Deklination (''der kalte Kaffee/ein kalter Kaffee/kalter Kaffee'')'
```

I get (with DB Browser for Sqlite) :

```
0 rows returned in 70ms from: select * from QuestionBank where category = 'Adjektiv - Deklination (''der kalte Kaffee/ein kalter Kaffee/kalter Kaffee'')'
```

also with " instead of ' ' it give the same result

```
 select * from QuestionBank where category = 'Adjektiv - Deklination ("der kalte Kaffee/ein kalter Kaffee/kalter Kaffee")'

0 rows returned in 72ms from: select * from QuestionBank where category = 'Adjektiv - Deklination ("der kalte Kaffee/ein kalter Kaffee/kalter Kaffee")'
```

how to deal with that problem ? in MS-Sql I would just make it a VARCHAR with N but how to make it here ?

here is a screenshot for my DB.

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A screenshot does not show if there are any special characters.

Comment: yes for the moment that's true, but the database keeps growing and growing and there will be certainly some special characters in the category column. I wanted to insert ANY values in it and not having problems retrieving data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the data from you screenshot, those are double quotes (`"`), not two single quotes (`'`) in the data:

```
SELECT *
FROM   QuestionBank
WHERE  category = 
       'Adjektiv - Deklination ("der kalte Kaffee/ein kalter Kaffee/kalter Kaffee")'
       -- Here -----------------^------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: The DB browser changes the " to a double ' automatically, but the result is always 0 rows, I'll add that to the question